# Как проверить, что все символы в строке одинаковые?

Tags: java, строки

Допустим есть массив стрингов. Как проверить, что какие-то строки в нём состоят только из одинаковых символов? Например "aaaa", "bbbbb","ccc"?

Пример:

```
String[] texts = new String[50_000];

text[0] = "aaa";

text[1] = "abcc";

text[2] = "ccccc";

text[3] = "bbbb";

text[4] = "cca";
```

Comment: и даже вообще никаких своих идей нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения этой задачи можно написать функцию, которая будет проверять каждую строку на предмет того, состоит ли она только из одинаковых символов. Вот пример такой функции на языке Java:

```
public static boolean isSameCharacters(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    char c = s.charAt(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) != c) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Эта функция принимает на вход строку **s** и проверяет, состоит ли она только из одинаковых символов. Если да, то функция возвращает **true**, иначе - **false**. Функция начинает проверку с первого символа строки **s**, сохраняет его в переменной **c** и сравнивает остальные символы с ним. Если какой-то символ отличается от **c**, то функция возвращает **false**. Если все символы одинаковые, то функция возвращает **true**.

Чтобы проверить все строки в массиве texts, можно пройтись по нему в цикле и вызвать функцию **isSameCharacters()** для каждой строки:

```
for (String s : texts) {
    if (isSameCharacters(s)) {
        System.out.println(s + " consists of same characters");
    }
}
```

Этот код пройдется по всем строкам в массиве **texts**, вызовет функцию **isSameCharacters()** для каждой из них и напечатает те, которые состоят только из одинаковых символов.

Answer (score 1):

Можно с применением метода `String::matches` и регулярного выражения, например: `"(.)\\1*"` множество символов после первого может быть пустым, т.е. будет возвращаться `true` для строки из одного символа:

```java
public static boolean allSame(String str) {
    return str != null && str.matches("(.)\\1*");
}
```

Если требуется, что после первого символа должен быть хотя бы один символ, регулярка меняется на `"(.)\\1+"`.

---

Аналогичный однострочник с использованием Stream API:

```java
public static boolean allSame(String str) {
    return str != null && !str.isEmpty() && str.chars().allMatch(c -> str.charAt(0) == c);
}
```